# Error comparing datetime field from mysql db to a varchar in mssql db

Tags: mysql, sql-server, datetime

I have a datetime field in a mysql db called CallDate.  I have a Varchar field in a mssql db called Actualdate.  I am trying to retrieve results for records where the dates of rows from the mysql db are newer than the newest row from the mssql db.  I can run the subquery without error but when I combine it with the mysql query part it fails with this error.

[MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.1.66]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONVERT(DATETIME, CallDate, 120 )

```
select *
from openquery(
[amr-aws-xyz],
'SELECT * from abc WHERE CallDate > 
(SELECT TOP(1) CONVERT(DATETIME, ActualDate, 120 )
FROM MyDB.dbo.CDR
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, ActualDate, 120) DESC)')
```

Comment: You're trying to use MS SQL Server `CONVERT()` syntax in a MySQL query. Your MySQL server is correctly rejecting the `CONVERT()` call.

Comment: I thought that as well but that specific subquery is querying a mssql db, even when i use CONVERT(ActualDate, DATETIME) instead of the mssql syntax it fails as well.